# NSInternalInconsistencyException Performance Metrics must provide 10 measurements when measuring performance in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, performance, xctest

When trying to measure performance of a `do try` block inside a `XCTestCase` class, I get `failed: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "Performance Metrics must provide 10 measurements."`.
My assertion inside of it also fails, but as soon as I take it out of the `self.measure` block, it works.

```
let name = "foo"  
    self.measure {
        do {
            _ = try myStore.controller.createObject(named: name)
        } catch let error {
            XCTAssert(false, "Should be able to create object named \(name): \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Anyone knows what's wrong with the way I have it inside `self.measure`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my `myStore.controller.createObject(named: name)` method throws an error when I try to create an object with the name that already exists. `self.measure` runs 10 times so I was trying to create objects with the same name.